# 3 vocabulary and taxonomies in this vocabularies

Tags: taxonomy-terms, uri, breadcrumbs

I want to use vocabulary and stored in separate taxonomy vocabularies to create urls, and breadcumbs; is it possible?

Drupal 7

I want to get the schema:
a vocabulary 1
   a taxonomy 1
   a taxonomy 2
b vocabulary 1
   b taxonomy 1
   b taxonomy 2
c vocabulary 1
   c taxonomy 1
   c taxonomy 2
effect to get :

User type in 1 node 
a vocabulary 1
   a taxonomy 1
b vocabulary 1
   b taxonomy 2
c vocabulary 1
   c taxonomy 1

breadcrumbs (diff vocabularies )
a taxonomy 1 >> b taxonomy 1 >> c taxonomy 1

url path for taxonomy:

a taxonomy 1 / b taxonomy 1 / c taxonomy 1 /

Comment: I'm not able to understand your question completely. However,  when creating paths automatically using a particular pattern (I think that is what your asking for), the module Pathauto (https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) is usually the way to go. Let me know if this suits your needs, or if your asking something else.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not well-asked but this is the answer:

1. Yes, you can have multiple vocabularies, multiple taxonomy terms in these vocabularies and also multiple child-terms in these taxonomy terms. It's one of the **core** functionality of Drupal.
2. Yes, the breadcrumbs can show the taxonomy hierarchy as you wanted but it depends on  the **theme** you use.
3. Yes, it's possible to show taxonomy terms in url with [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.

Comment: hello , thks 4 reply my question is too complicated for my expirance with english :/

Comment: @DoktorKarp, welcome. Please mark this as answer if it helps you.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the current +1 in this answer is from @DoktorKarp ... because I thought upvoting requires a rep of at least 15, no? With a rep of "1" you can only ACCEPT an answer ... Anyway, +1 from me now ...